# Measuring rate of events with Micrometer

Tags: dropwizard, micrometer, spring-micrometer

In Dropwizard there is something like meter:
https://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#meters
It lets me measure rate of events just by invoking `mark()` method on the metric.

How can I do that in Micrometer?

I can use timers, but I don't want to pass `Timer.Sample` object to wherever place where I need to call `stop()` method.

The other missing thing in Micrometer comparing to Dropwizard is a metric that can contain a text message, like gauge in Dropwizard.

Answer (score 5):

Micrometer leverages the strengths of modern metrics backends. So the specific answer to your question depends on which you are using. Take Prometheus for example. The backend can calculate the rate for you.

If you are measuring the rate of how often something is happening you can determine that using a `Counter`. Take the `logback_events_total` counter as an example. It is merely counting the number for log messages written.

When alerting or graphing you can then write a query like `rate(logback_events_total[1m])` and you will be able to see the rate at which logs have been writen at the `1m` rate. You have the ability to change to window from `1m`, to `5m` or `1h` without changing the code.

Regarding text based metrics, those aren't useful for alerting (but can be useful when using a `join` clause). The typical solution in that case is to create a gauge with a value of 1 or 0 and make your text value a tag. For example:

```
registry.gaugle('app.info', Tags.of("version","1.0.beta3", this, () -> 1.0));
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. In DropWizard we were able to use meters to get the rate of events per minute, but in Micrometer we could not find a built-in way that worked for us.

We needed rates for counters and percentiles for timers. The PrometheusMeterRegistry gave us percentiles, but no rates.

So we built our own Gauge that tracks a Counter. Every time `getValue()` is called, it fetches the value from the counter and adds it to the right bucket with the current timestamp. Then from all available measurements it can compute the rate over the last minute.

It looks like this:

```java
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Clock;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class OneMinuteRateGauge {

    private static final int WINDOW_SECONDS = 60;

    private final Supplier<Double> valueSupplier;
    private final LinkedList<Bucket> buckets;
    private final Clock clock;

    public OneMinuteRateGauge(String name, Supplier<Double> valueSupplier, MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this(name, valueSupplier, meterRegistry, Clock.SYSTEM);
    }

    public OneMinuteRateGauge(String name, Supplier<Double> valueSupplier, MeterRegistry meterRegistry, Clock clock) {
        this.valueSupplier = valueSupplier;
        this.buckets = new LinkedList<>();
        Gauge.builder(name, this::getValue).register(meterRegistry);
        this.clock = clock;

        // Collect one measurement so we have a faster start
        getValue();
    }

    public synchronized double getValue() {
        // Update the last bucket or create a new one
        long now_millis = clock.monotonicTime() / 1_000_000;
        long now_seconds = now_millis / 1_000;
        short millis = (short) (now_millis - (now_seconds * 1000));
        double value = valueSupplier.get();
        if (buckets.size() != 0 && buckets.getLast().getSeconds() == now_seconds) {
            buckets.getLast().updateValue(millis, value);
        } else {
            buckets.addLast(new Bucket(now_seconds, millis, value));
        }

        // Delete all buckets outside the window except one
        while (2 < buckets.size() && buckets.get(1).getSeconds() + WINDOW_SECONDS < now_seconds) {
            buckets.pollFirst();
        }

        if (buckets.size() == 1) {
            // Not enough data
            return 0;
        } else if (now_seconds <= buckets.getFirst().getSeconds() + WINDOW_SECONDS) {
            // First bucket is inside the window
            return buckets.getLast().getValue() - buckets.getFirst().getValue();
        } else {
            // Find the weighted average between the first two points
            Bucket p0 = buckets.get(0);
            Bucket p1 = buckets.get(1);
            double px = now_millis - (WINDOW_SECONDS * 1000);
            double m = (p1.getValue() - p0.getValue()) / (p1.getTimestampInMillis() - p0.getTimestampInMillis());
            double py = m * (px - p0.getTimestampInMillis()) + p0.getValue();
            return value - py;
        }
    }
}

public class Bucket {

    private long seconds; // Seconds since 1.1.1970, used as bucket ID
    private short millis; // 0-999, used for a more exact calculation
    private double value;

    public Bucket(long seconds, short millis, double value) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.millis = millis;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public long getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public long getTimestampInMillis() {
        return seconds * 1000 + millis;
    }

    public void updateValue(short millis, double value) {
        this.millis = millis;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

An alternative way could have been to use CompositeMeterRegistry on the top level and then add both a PrometheusMeterRegistry and a StepMeterRegistry. Prometheus reports percentiles and Step reports rates. Our monitoring system would then have to query two endpoints.

This was a temporary solution until we modified our monitoring system to read the prometheus endpoint and calculate its own rates.